# Asked a question yesterday and SE metrics say that it was today

Tags: bug, design, questions, time, timezone

I am currently in Portugal (UTC timezone - [which is the one used by SE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp7jO.png), and it is `2021-01-09` `11:31AM`.

I have asked a question yesterday, `2021-01-08`, at `02:54PM`

[image]

However, if one looks at the metrics under the title of the question, it says that the question was asked "Today"

[image]

[Here is the link to the question.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/144745/69100)

Comment: @RobertColumbia it is not the same question. He is considering the class "post-signature owner grid--cell" (the first image I share in the question) and I am asking about the class "grid fw-wrap pb8 mb16 bb bc-black-075" (the last image I share in my question).

Comment: That's totally not relevant. The data is the same, no matter where it appears.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating how are you defining what is/isn't relevant? In the first image it appears "20 hours" in the second one "Today". It may come from the same info, but the information displayed is not the same.

Answer (score 4):

You asked the question 20 hours ago. `<24 hours == Today` is the logic here. [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design) I would say.